# Is it possible to integrate a web service in a spring + JSF project?

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, jsf-2.2

I need to establish a connexion between my android client and my spring + JSF server
I need to send files from my android client and receive them in the server side
for that, i tried to send the file directly to a bean which contains this function

```
      @Component
      @Scope("request")
      @Path("/file")
      public class RestWebService {
      @POST
      @Path("/upload")
      @Consumes(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
      public String uploadFile(
      @FormParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
      @FormParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
      @QueryParam("inputFileName") String inputFileName) throws               FileNotFoundException{
      System.out.println("start upload");
       System.out.println(fileDetail.getFileName());
       return "";
}
```

and i added to my web.xml this lines:

```
       <display-name>Restful Web Application</display-name>
       <servlet>
       <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-     class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
         <param-value>com.test.WebService</param-value>
         </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

but it seems that JSF block the connexion 
i want to know if it is possible to continue in this way or i must change this solution and in this case how ??

Comment: "Seems that JSF is blocking… " How did you come to tbis conclusion?

Comment: in this case JSF is the controller and it connect views with beans and method ???

Comment: Yes, **views** with beans and method, but not  a Webservice is not a 'view'. And if you you do think it is blocking, why did you not post the JSF config part of your web.xml? And try without jsf then. Does it work then? And what about the response in the client?

Answer (score 1):

JSF not blocking REST access url. You need just properly configuration.
You can have a look JSF/REST project which is run under wildfly, you can access REST via url within JSF application, please have a look
https://github.com/armdev/wildfly-jsf2.3-web